# Can't get simple Object oriented row count to display

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Been struggling with this for two days (and the rest). Read a couple of dozen posts from this site, been reading lots from w3 schools and lots of other resources online.

All I'm trying to do is show how many people have signed a petition.
After many failures, I wiped what I had and started from scratch. 
I tried a few bits of code from w3 to check my connection to my database. The PDO didn't work at all, but object oriented worked fine. (Showed "connection successful" on my page.)
So then tried the code below, which I took from the PHP manual and still can't get it to work.
Would really appreciate some help.

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my user", "my password", "my db");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

if ($result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT Code, Name FROM 'wp_rm_submissions' ORDER BY Name")) {

    /* determine number of rows result set */
    $row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    printf("So far %d people have signed the petition.\n", $row_cnt);

    /* close result set */
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}

/* close connection */
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

I've also tried it without the single quotes around the table name.
My website is [here](http://becomingjohnnynova.com/temp/).
It's a WordPress site, if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need  to count the records use `select count`:

```
  SELECT count(Code) as count FROM wp_rm_submissions
```

This query will return a resultset with one record, the record will have a field called `count` and it's value will be the number of records stored in the `wp_rm_submissions` table.

A very very very simple example in php, using mysqli, would be:

```
  
 <?php 
    // connect to mysql
    $mysqli = new mysqli('host','user','password','schema');
    // execute the query
    $result = $mysqli->query('SELECT count(Code) as count FROM wp_rm_submissions');
    // fetch the record as an associative array
    $record = $result->fetch_assoc();
    // get the value 
    $count  = (int)$record['count'];

    $mysqli->close(); 

    printf("So far %d people have signed the petition.\n", $count);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it didn't work. I got "Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object" I googled that and tried a couple of things but don't understand all of this that well, so I'm still unable to get this to work.

Comment: I pasted the above example changing only 'host' 'user' etc. Was I meant to change something else as well?

Comment: Well, make sure your SQL is correct. When there is an error mysql::query returns`false`. The `$mysqli` object holds the error message and error code, so you can print `$mysqli->error` to see the **error message** and `$mysqli->errno` to see the **error code**. If you copy/pasted my code, make sure the table name is correct and the `Code` field exists. Also, take a look at the official documentation, there are some examples there too http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: Success! I'll show my ignorance here a bit. I struggled for another four hours before finally coming up with... SELECT count(*), instead of SELECT count(Code). Your example worked perfect with it. Adding the asterisk to my original code finally printed the result, but the wrong result. Have no idea why. Thanks very much for your help and patience.